# Не скачивает файлы с интернета

Tags: c#, winforms

Простой код должен скачать файл на рабочий стол, но ни в какую не хочет. Пробовал заменить ссылку на другой хостинг, пробовал менять путь, запускать от имени администратора - никак.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string link = @""; //ссылка
string downloadFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("test.7z");
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), @"C:\Users\User\Desktop" + downloadFileName);
```

Пробовал разный код (как и разные проекты) - толку ноль. В чем может быть проблема? Ссылки все рабочие, запускал в режиме инкогнито. В консоли такое ощущение, будто она пропускает эту часть кода...

Этот вариант тестовый, поэтому написан так себе.

p.s я знаю, что использовать webclient - идея так себе. можете не говорить об этом

Comment: @"C:\Users\User\Desktop" попробуй сделать  @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\", с виду поможет

Comment: вместо `DownloadFileAsync` используйте `DownloadFile`. Вместо конкатенации строк путей `путь1 + путь2` используйте `Path.Combine(путь1, путь2)`. `new Uri` можно не делать, метод `DownloadFile` принимает ссылку в виде строки.

Comment: @aepot это уже было испробовано.

помог ответ выше

Comment: @Akakiy ответ выше как раз и решается через `Path.Combine`, он автоматически добавляет слеши и убирает лишние там, где надо. Что вы меня обманываете. `webClient.DownloadFileAsync(link, Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop", downloadFileName));` - так вы точно не пробовали. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог ответ RottenRat:
Нужно было всего лишь поставить `\` в конец пути:

```
@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
```